# C# How do I append code to the end of a running .NET .EXE, preferably from inside that .EXE?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, exe, portability

Can a running **.NET .EXE** append data to itself? What's stopping it?

I could launch a separate process to do it just fine.

But I can't figure out how to write to itself while it's running. Is there anyway to do this? **IN .NET**

EDIT: And preferably no hacky solutions like write it out somewhere else then copy/rename

EDIT2: Clarifying type of executeable

EDIT3: *Purpose*: Writing binary stream to my running EXE file allows me to then ***parse the .EXE file on disk for those bytes and use them in the program***. Without having to create any new files or registry entries or stuff like that. It is self contained. This is extremely convenient.

EDIT4: For those against this file, please thinking about the functions of: **FILE ZIPPING**, **DLL LINKING**, and **PORTABLE APPLICATIONS** before trying to discredit this idea,

Comment: "I know once an .EXE is running you can insert bytes to the end of it" - uhhhh, not quite. Or at least, it's certainly not as simple as that. What gives you that idea?

Comment: I think you need to understand how a program-loader works first, as well as how the PE image format works. A Win32 PE executable program (`.exe` files, etc) is not a linear list of instructions where you can simply tack on more instructions at the end: it's a structured format which has all manner of transformations applied to it when it's loaded by the OS (e.g. relocation, base addresses, etc).

Comment: Umm.. No, you can't just *insert bytes to the end of it*. Also, trying to do so is going to attract immediate attention from any halfway decent virus scanner.

Comment: @Ken White I don't care about virus scanners this is my own program

Comment: [Please explain what your goal is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); pretend you actually could “insert bytes to the end of it”; what is that going to do for you?

Comment: @Dour High Arch I could then read those, bytes, knowing exactly where they are, and use them in my program.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it should be hard to grasp. Is adding data to a running EXE bad in some way?

Comment: "I could then read those, bytes" - why not just use a separate file for this data?

Comment: Why do we zip files together?

Comment: “I could then read those, bytes, knowing exactly where they are, and use them in my program.” Then write them to a user file. Everything you are asking for is supported by writing to a user file.

Comment: @Dour High Arch Then the user has to find that file if they want to move the app huh? This is like a brain-dead concept. Why do we zip files together? Why is the application not functioning as its own zip file?

Comment: No the user certainly does not have to “find that file”; there are multiple places, from [special folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-5.0) to secure storage, that come built-in to Windows the user does not have to find. If only you would explain what you are trying to accomplish with all this we could help you.

Comment: Windows has supported portable apps since the MS-DOS era. There's a dozen different ways of making them, if only you told us what you are trying to do we could help. Instead you came up with an unworkable idea you will not let go of. .NET assemblies have supported loadable sections since the beginning, but they are signed so you can't change them. This is done to prevent hackers from injecting keyloggers, trojans, viruses and sniffers into published apps.

Comment: @Dai, yes you can, it is trivial and it works fine (and I did it, so I know from experience). However writing to running program (i.e. used file) is different, but only to respect of locked (or not) file.

Comment: While I voted for reopening I have to say you are extremely lazy -- you should already check if the writing anything to running program file is possible or not. If it is possible, end of the story, if not, you should check what process locked the file (and probably it is only end of the story, given you only accept direct writing). In general appending to non-running program file is possible and it works fine.

Comment: Two ways of achieving this spring to mind:

The first way is to write a program that can recompile itself with the new data. For example, invoking Roslyn somehow with its own source code.
The second way is to embed the data as a resource within the executable, then recompile with the updated data when saving.

A quick search on Google will tell you that neither option is particularly fun to implement.

There are many good reasons to _not_ bake the user's data directly into the app's executable file, besides the obvious difficulty of doing so.

Comment: I would say this is a terrible idea even if you could get it to work. By mixing code and user data you make it almost impossible to change them independently. Consider if you have a bug in that crashes the program when reading some specific kind of data. The exe becomes useless since it will always crash on startup, and there is no simple way to delete the broken data. And if you fix any bugs, it will be much more cumbersome to transfer the user data to the new version. Not to mention the risk of leaking sensitive information if you transfer the .exe to someone else.

Comment: Just tried the Hex editor you suggested, it doesn't show a warning for poor coding but it doesn't save anything to the image file if it's running. Just try it, overwrite the first two MZ bytes with 0 and save, then close the program and restart it, it won't get corrupted! If you reload it in the editor the bytes will be there again. Also you can't close the handle even with admin privileges, Windows kernel is keeping it open.

Comment: @GrowingBrick Add the bytes to the end of the file. They are there while the file is open, and after its closed, and after it's reopened. The file image can be appended to while its running

Comment: The requirements left only potentially malicious and/or unstable ways. None of them guarantee proper result saving. More of that, the "portable" definition is highly restricted to a single file. That's totally wrong. Please, take a look at its definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application. You can have it "portable" in a directory - a few files. Including ALL referenced GAC DLLs. And with no registry or OS settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite all the negativity, there is a clean way to do this:

The way I have found only requires the program be executed on an NTFS drive.

The trick is to have your app copy itself to an alternate stream as soon as it's launched, then execute that image and immediately close itself. This can be easily done with the commands:

```
type myapp.exe > myapp.exe:image
forfiles /m myapp.exe /c myapp.exe:image
```

Once your application is running from an alternate stream (myapp.exe:image), it is free to modify the original file (myapp.exe) and read the data that's stored within it. The next time the program starts, the modified application will be copied to the alternate stream and executed.

This allows you to get the effect of an executable writing to itself while running, without dealing with any extra files and allows you to store all settings within a single .exe file.

The file must be executed on an NTFS partition, but that is not a big deal since all Windows installations use this format. You can still copy the file to other filesystems, you just cannot execute it there.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of bad consequences for storing data this way, as said in the comments, but there's a bigger problem: the answer to "What's stopping it?" question. The Windows PE loader **locks** the image file for writing while in execution, so you can't get an *HANDLE* to the file with write permissions, as `NtCreateFile` and `NtOpenFile` system calls with *FILE_WRITE_DATA* option will fail, as well as any attempt to delete the file. This block is implemented at kernel level and set during the `NtCreateProcess` system call, before the process and its modules entry point are actually called.

The only dirty trick possible without writing data to the disk, sending it to a remote server and without kernel privileges is to use another process via an helper executable, code injection or command-line arguments scripts (e.g. with PowerShell) which can kill your process releasing the lock, append data to the end of file and restart it. Of course these options have even worse consequences, I wrote it only to make clear the OS limitations (made by purpose) and why no professional software uses this technique to store data.

EDIT: since you are so determined to accomplish this behavior I post a proof of concept for appending data via helper executable (file copy), the method relies on executing a new copy of the image in TEMP folder, passing the path to the original executable so it can be "written" because isn't running and locked. **FOR READERS I SUGGEST TO DON'T USE IT IN PRODUCTION**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace BadStorage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var temp = Path.GetTempPath();
            var exePath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            if (exePath.IndexOf(temp, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 && args.Length > 0)
            {
                // "Real" main
                var originalExe = args[0];
                if (File.Exists(originalExe))
                {
                    // Your program code...

                    byte[] data = { 0xFF, 0xEE, 0xDD, 0xCC };
                    // Write
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(originalExe, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                        fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                    // Read
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(originalExe, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                    {
                        fs.Seek(-data.Length, SeekOrigin.End);
                        fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Self-copy
                var exeCopy = Path.Combine(temp, Path.GetFileName(exePath));
                File.Copy(exePath, exeCopy, true);
                var p = new Process()
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                    {
                        FileName = exeCopy,
                        Arguments = $"\"{exePath}\"",
                        UseShellExecute = false
                    }
                };
                p.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can execute it in another processes memory space and write to the image on disk. Is there a clean an effective way of doing this? Or a better way? Hasn't anyone wanted to do this? Wouldn't it be nice? I'm sick of people telling me things are impossible.

Comment: Yes, as I said another process with another image file can terminate yours and write the data. Even if it's far from clean it's possible. No better ways are possible because Windows is preventing you from doing it.

Comment: I just did it. Run an Exe file, an open it up in a hex editor append bytes to the END of the file. Hit save. Those bytes will be there during the program's execution and afterwards. I've done it, a million times. Bytes can be appended to running EXE files. They won't be in memory, but they will be on the disk. Go look it up.

Comment: Look, the idea is not completely without merit. You are clearly very committed to it. Since nobody here will change your mind, I suggest you familiarise yourself with the PE file format (ELF if you like Linux) and build a very small proof-of-concept that you can build from. I suggest dropping .NET to start with to simplify things. If it works, at the very least it will be interesting to see how you achieved it, and at best you'll achieve this portable app revolution you seem to want. Personally I'm just hoping your decorum on the internet changes, as frankly on this thread it was a disgrace.

Comment: @8vtwo That hex editor can't do miracles and I tested that doesn't work with my executable, maybe the process you are editing is just copying to another location so the file isn't locked (like a self-extraction program). I'm updating the answer to demonstrate this method.

Comment: @GrowingBrick that is likely the real reason why OP is under the false assumption that files can be unlocked while running. He would have been able to figure it out himself if he simply used the task manager to see the file origin of the exe or its command line arguments. Either that, or its running as a service in another process. I doubt he would even be able to provide a reproducible sample to prove his claims.

Comment: @John I don't know if it's possible cause I have zero experience with it, but maybe (and this is a big maybe) the hex editor in question is using VSS to make a shadow copy of the running exe, and then just waiting for the file lock to clear to overwrite it?

Comment: @John Just for your own understanding of how Windows works, it is possible to have a running executable with no image on disk. You can do this by executing an exe from an alternate stream, then delete the file and the stream. The file will be running but there will be no code representing it anywhere on the disk. There are probably other numerous ways to create this effect. I have done a few of them. Your idea that a file in Windows "Must be locked" while running is incorrect.

Comment: @toneo On the contrary, I believe I have the best solution this far using .NET. But it has not been fully implemented. Why would you recommend I use an ancient technology when there are much better tools now?

Comment: @8vtwo I suggested that because editing an executable is non-trivial and so it makes sense to start simple. By the way, .NET fills a particular niche, it is not 'better' than everything else (and I say that as a total .NET stan). Incidentally this answer _does_ run fine, so I guess Windows doesn't look at anything past the 'end' of the exe when checking that the file's valid?

Comment: @8vtwo If you like, there's another solution using alternate streams that works just fine. It's less hacky but will only work in NTFS filesystems - copy it onto a USB with a FAT filesystem and you'll lose your data.